# Localized Brownouts in micro-controller reasons

Tags: c, embedded

In "An Embedded Software Primer" book, I read that

> if a chip must change many of its outputs signals from high to low or
>   low to high at the same time, that chip will need a lot of power to
>   change these signals. They are going to need more power so we need the
>   -decoupling capacitors- , otherwise a localized brownout can occur for a few microseconds.

..
I need a sample code in C or Assembly that shows how can a chip change its output signals at the same time ! 
..
*book link: http://www.staroceans.org/kernel-and-driver/An%20Embedded%20Software%20Primer%20(Pearson-1999).pdf* chapter 2 page 20

Comment: LATA = 0x00; LATA = 0xFF;

Comment: Does the book carry on to say "If this situation occurs then use this book to hit the hardware designer on the head and tell him to do his job correctly."?

Comment: @andrew , yes it does subtly say that in both chapter 2 and 3, but in a more gentle way

Answer (score 0):

With an ATMega328, you can write the following:

```
void setup()
{
 DDRD = 0xff;
}

void loop() {
 PORTD = 0xff;
 delay(1000);
 PORTD = 0x00;
 delay(1000);
}
```

where PORTD refers to pins 0-7 as an 8-bit word from low to high. DDRD sets the pinmode for PORTD, where 0 is input and 1 is output.

Comment: Thanks @Eisen, but I wonder wouldn't the delay(1000); satisfy this?  -change its output signals "at the same time" -

Comment: Sorry, I just saw the notification for this reply. Can you rephrase your question? I read it three times and still don't quite understand your meaning.